# Oracle Sql and Powershell : Execute query, print/output results

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell

I need a way to execute a SQL (by importing a .SQL script)  on a remote Oracle DB using PowerShell. In addition to this I am also trying to output the results in an .xls format in a desired folder location. To add to the fun, I would also want to run this task on an automatic schedule. Please help !

I have gotten so far :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName ("System.Data.OracleClient") | Out-Null
$connection = "my TNS entry"
$queryString = "my SQL query"    
$command = new-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($queryString, $connection) 
$connection.Open()
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
$tempArr = @()
#read all rows into a hash table
while ($reader.Read())
  {
    $row = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
    {
        $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
    }
    #convert hashtable into an array of PSObjects
    $tempArr+= new-object psobject -property $row
  }
$connection.Close()
write-host "Conn State--> " $connection.State
$tmpArr | Export-Csv "my File Path" -NoTypeInformation
$Error[0] | fl -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to drive `sqlplus.exe` via powershell. To execute the sql and get the output you do this:

```
 $result = sqlplus.exe @file.sql [credentials/server] 
 #parse result into CSV here which can be loaded into excel
```

You can schedule this script with something like:

```
 schtasks.exe /create /TN sqlplus /TR "Powershell -File script.ps1" /ST 10 ...
```

For this you need to have sqlplus installed (it comes with oracle express and you could install it without it). This obviously introduces dependency that is not needed but sqlplus could be used to examine the database and do any kind of thing which might be good thing to have around.

Comment: majkinetor , I would pretty much like to do this without the sqlplus.exe method. I was able to get a little ahead with the script with the latest edit. Thoughts ?